How to Redact Sensitive Data in Debug Logs from Python Libraries (httpx, httpcore, hpack)
I am working on an application that uses the Supabase Python client, and I’ve run into an issue with sensitive data like tokens appearing in debug logs. These logs include REST API calls that expose sensitive query parameters and headers, which I'd like to redact.
For example, here are some log snippets:
[2024-12-09 14:32:00] [DEBUG] [hpack.hpack] Decoded 68, consumed 1 bytes

[2024-12-09 14:32:00] [DEBUG] [hpack.hpack] Decoded (b'content-location', b'/sensitive_table?sensitive_token=eq.abc-1234-567899888-23333-33333-333333-333333'), total consumed 70 bytes, indexed True

[2024-12-09 14:32:00] [DEBUG] [httpcore.http2] receive_response_headers.complete return_value=(200 (b'content-location', b'/sensitive_table?sensitive_token=eq.abc-1234-567899888-23333-33333-333333-333333'))

These logs contain sensitive information like the sensitive_token in query parameters and other sensitive details in the request paths. I need to ensure that these values are redacted in logs.

What I Tried:
I set up a logging.Filter in Python to redact sensitive data from logs. Here’s an example of the filter I implemented:
class SensitiveDataFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> bool:
        # Redacts sensitive data
        record.msg = re.sub(r"abc-[0-9a-f\-]+", "[REDACTED-TOKEN]", record.msg)
        return True

# Applying the filter
for logger_name in ["httpx", "httpcore", "hpack", "supabase"]:
    logging.getLogger(logger_name).addFilter(SensitiveDataFilter())

Unfortunately, even with this filter, sensitive data still appears in logs, especially in debug output from libraries like httpx, httpcore, and hpack. It seems these libraries generate logs in a way that bypasses the filter or logs data outside the msg attribute of LogRecord.

Is there a recommended way to redact sensitive data from debug logs, especially for libraries like httpx, httpcore, and hpack?
Are there specific hooks or middleware options for libraries like httpx to intercept and redact sensitive data?
Thanks.
